The repository does not have a Release file. Error
Err:7 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/oisf/suricata-stable/ubuntu lunar Release
404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.80 443]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/oisf/suricata-stable/ubuntu lunar Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
I was trying to integrate IDS (Suricata) with wazuh and this error occurred
